# Is it possible to start multi physical node hadoop clustster using docker?

Tags: hadoop, docker, cluster-computing

I've seen searching for a way to start docker on multiple physical machines and connect them to a hadoop cluster, so far I only found ways to start a cluster locally on 1 machine. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well provision a multinode hadoop cluster with docker.

Please look at some posts below which will give you some insights on doing it:

http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/06/19/multinode-hadoop-cluster-on-docker/

[Run a hadoop cluster on docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008522/run-a-hadoop-cluster-on-docker-containers)